C# Linq join between two sub tables
I have two tables
Existing table
{{ID: 1, Codes: { 1, 2, 3 }},
 {ID: 2, Codes: { 4, 5, 6, 7 }}, 
 {ID: 3, Codes: { 8, 9, 10, 11 }}}

and an incoming table
{{Codes: { 1, 2, 3 }},
 {Codes: { 4, 5, 6, 7 }},
 {Codes: { 13, 14, 15, 16 }}}

I want to get the new row out of the incoming data. So, new data can be inserted into my existing table. I want the putout to be the following:
 {{Codes: { 13, 14, 15, 16 }}}

Can someone help me write a Linq query?

Which data type is the "Codes" column?

Join between two tables, but your data from incoming table with all the codes are "x".

IDs are auto-generated in the existing table and incoming data doesn't need that. the list of Codes is int in this case, but that doesn't matter does it?

Ok so you are describing the entity not the actual database table.

Two enumerable objects

In sounds like you need something like incoming.Where(i => !existing.Any(e => e.Codes.SequenceEquals(i.Codes))).

LINQ query is built from classes. Show classes and real input data. Aslo specify ORM which do you use and version if any.

LINQ doesn't need a class or an ORM

@LeBlues - When comparing the lists of codes, must they all match or does any shared member count as a match? Also, are the lists ordered, so that two equivalent lists will always have the same order?

@LeBlues, it is debatable, but you do not play with integers or strings, here we see complex structures. If you use EF (IQueryable), for example, LINQ is tightly coupled with it's vesrion. EF uses translator which may not handle specific constructions.

Here you go:
var newRows = incomingTable
    .Where(incomingRow => !existingTable
        .Any(existingRow => existingRow.Codes.Intersect(incomingRow.Codes).Any()));


What if I have multiple Code columns to compare?  {{CodesA: { 1, 2, 3 }, {CodesB: { 1, 2, 3 }} in income,ing and existing,

@LeBlues - First study the current expression so that you understand what it is doing. Next repeat the inner comparison test, tailored as needed, and join those conditions using the logical-and operator &&.

@LeBlues existingRow.CodesA.Intersect(incomingRow.CodesA).Any() && existingRow.CodesB.Intersect(incomingRow.CodesB).Any()
